# How to prove this theorem about the product of multinomial sums in rings?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, analysis

Assume $(R,+,\cdot)$ is a commutative ring with 1, $x\in R$, and $(a_j)_{j\in\mathbb N}$ and $(b_j)_{j\in\mathbb N}$ are sequences satisfying $i>n\to a_i=0$ ($j>m\to b_j=0$). Then, how to prove the following formula
$\boxed{\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i\cdot \sum_{j=0}^mb_jx^j=\sum_{k=0}^{n+m}\Big(\sum_{i=0}^ka_ib_{k-i}x^{k}\Big)}$

I think mathematical induction should be used, but I can't deduce m + 1 from m:
$\begin{array}{l}
&\displaystyle \Big(\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i\Big)\cdot\Big(\sum_{j=0}^{m+1}b_jx^j\Big)\\
=&\displaystyle \Big(\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i\Big)\cdot\Big(\sum_{j=0}^mb_jx^j+b_{m+1}x^{m+1}\Big)\\
=&\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n+m}\Big(\sum_{i=0}^ka_ib_{k-i}x^k\Big)+\Big(\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i\Big)(b_{m+1}x^{m+1})\\
=&\text{what should I do next???}\\
=&\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n+m+1}\Big(\sum_{i=0}^ka_{i}b_{k-i}x^k\Big)
\end{array}$
Can you give me a complete proof or some general ideas? Please.

Comment: I suspect you mean a "commutative ring with $1$". Or possibly "ring with $1$", and assume $x$ is central.

Comment: I don't see why a straightforward induction on $n+m$ doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I attached my process. I can only do the first two trivial steps.@ancientmathematician

Comment: By induction on $n$ you prove that  $(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i x^i )bx^s=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i b x^{i+s}$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. Could you please write down the whole process? I'm really driven crazy by this problem. Thank you very much!@ancientmathematician

Answer (score 1):

First, a simplification: we don't need these $x$'s; replace $a_i x^i$ by $a_i$  and $b_j x^j$ by $b_j$.

Second, let's deal with the special case $m=n$.

So our proposition is equivalent to

$P(n)$: If $a_i=b_i$ for all $i>n$ then $\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i \sum_{j=0}^{n} b_j=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\sum_{i+j=k,i\leqslant n,j\leqslant n} a_i b_j$.

The root case $n=0$ is trivial to check true.

Now let us prove that if $P(n)$ is true so is $P(n+1)$.

First we work with the Left Hand Side using at the end $P(n)$.
$$ 
\begin{eqnarray}
&\ &\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} a_i \sum_{j=0}^{n+1} b_j\\
&=&\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i  +a_{n+1}\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n} b_j +b_{n+1}\right)\\
&=&\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i  \sum_{j=0}^{n} b_j
+a_{n+1}\left(\sum_{j=0}^n b_j\right)
+\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i\right) b_{n+1} +a_{n+1}b_{n+1}\\
&=& \sum_{k=0}^{2n}\sum_{i+j=k,i\leqslant n, j\leqslant n} a_i b_j 
+a_{n+1}\left(\sum_{j=0}^n b_j\right)
+\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i\right) b_{n+1} +a_{n+1}b_{n+1}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Next we work with the Right Hand Side, dealing first with the "extra" terms produced by $a_{n+1}$ and $b_{n+1}$.
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
&\ &\sum_{k=0}^{2n+2}\sum_{i+j=k,i\leqslant n+1,j\leqslant n+1} a_i b_j\\
&=& \sum_{k=0}^{2n+2}
\left(\sum_{i+j=k,i\leqslant n,j\leqslant n} a_i b_j
+\sum_{i+j=k,i=n+1,j\leqslant n} a_i b_j
+\sum_{i+j=k,i\leqslant n,j= n+1} a_i b_j
+\sum_{i+j=k,i=n+1,j=n+1} a_i b_j
\right)\\
&=& \sum_{k=0}^{2n+2}
\sum_{i+j=k,i\leqslant n,j\leqslant n} a_i b_j
+ \sum_{j=0}^{n} a_{n+1} b_j 
+\sum_{i=0}^n a_i b_{n+1}+a_{n+1} b_{n+1}\\
&=& \sum_{k=0}^{2n}
\sum_{i+j=k,i\leqslant n,j\leqslant n} a_i b_j
+ \sum_{j=0}^{n} a_{n+1} b_j 
+\sum_{i=0}^n a_i b_{n+1}+a_{n+1} b_{n+1}.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

The two expressions are equal: it is an easy lemma that $c\cdot\sum_{i=0}^n d_i=\sum_{i=0}^n c\cdot d_i$.

The "general" case for $m,n$ can be deduced from $P(\max\{m,n\})$.